# selenium grid + registering RC to it

Tags: selenium, grid, selenium-grid

i started hub with ant ,i dont to start rc using ant instead
i want to invoke it from code .iam using junit to run rc .please
suggest me how??

Comment: why do you want to start it programmatically? Grid is an "infrastructural" tool to make tests run faster so in my opinion should always be on.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do this, take a look at the build.xml file.  The "launch-remote-control" task should give you all the information you need.  You can see the Java class being invoked as well as the arguments being passed through.  You'll need to make sure you have everything in the vendor/ directory on your classpath, too.